# Hard Drive doesn't show in Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, recovery

I was trying to go back to OS X El Capitan with Recovery Mode, but after agreeing to the T&C, it tells me to choose a HD where to install the update, but it doesn't show up. What can I do?
I'm currently running macOS 10.15.6 w/ my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

[image]

EDIT: This is what the disk utility GUI and what the `diskutil list` shows.
[image]

Comment: what is the output of recovery mode's `diskutil list` and/or recovery mode's GUI Disk Utility?

Comment: Just added it to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Going back' & 'update' are mutually exclusive terms.

You will need to re-format the drive to HFS+ first from Disk Utility. El Capitan cannot read or understand the APFS disk format that Catalina uses.

Your edit suggests you are still in Catalina & that your disk is currently APFS.
You will need to start from your external El Capitan boot medium [or from Internet Recovery] in order to be able to format your boot drive [you cannot format the drive you are booted from, for obvious reasons.]
Select the Physical disk in the left column [Apple SSD] & select Erase. Set to GUID/HFS Extended, Journalled.

Comment: Where does that option appear in Disk Utility?

Comment: Click on the drive and there is a **button** that says "erase". It's grayed out in the question's picture, but still there.

Comment: Hi! I actually didn't need my whole HD to downgrade to El Capitan, so I ended up creating a Partition of the HD with format MacOS Extended (Journaled) where I could install El Capitan using Recovery mode. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score -2):

You’re looking to downgrade to an earlier version of macOS. There are several ways of going about it. Be sure to read through the methods carefully before you start executing, as they involve erasing your disk, which is irreversible.
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/downgrade-macos-version/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.