# Hard drive not showing in Recovery Mode despite reformat in HFS+

Tags: hard-drive, partition, disk-format, diskutil, internet-recovery

Same issue as related in this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400275/hard-drive-doesnt-show-in-recovery-mode) but I already did the following:

- Re-created a new GPT (GUID) partition table (using GParted, Ubuntu)
- Created an HFS+ partition specifically for my MacOS
- Re-created an EFI system partition of +500Mb

And yet, when using the Internet Recovery Mode, two things happen:

1. The wrong MacOS is being downloaded (Mac OS X Yosemite, instead of Monterrey)
2. The HFS+ partition created does not show.

---

**What did I miss?**

A possible solution would be to reformat the hard drive using Diskutil (Terminal, Recovery Mode) but no idea how to target the correct hard drive.

---

This what my partition table looks like from GParted:
[image]

And this is what my Disk Utility shows on Recovery Mode:
[image]

---

Things to take into consideration:

- I used to have an APFS hard drive before. But that must have been replaced by the HFS+ partition.
- I did not use FileVault or encrypted the disk (have had a lot of problems in using that).

Comment: You may want to add the model of Mac you have to your original question. Also holding COMMAND-OPTION-R for recovery mode will install the latest supported macOS that is currently available, rather than the version shipped with your Mac.

Comment: @SteveChambers: Based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395129/cannot-dual-boot-macos-ubuntu), I would assume 2017 MacBook Pro Intel-based.

Answer (score 0):

Following @SteveChambers's suggestion, I pressed & hold **COMMAND** + **OPTION** + **R** when powering on my Mac and it did download the latest version of MacOS disk utility which displayed my HFS+ partition.

Not ideal, does not solve the issue (HFS+ partition should be read & manipulated by older versions of disk utility) but it is a good temporary workaround.

Comment: Have you considered that a earliest version of macOS that 2017 MacBook Pro can install is Sierra (version 10.12.5) and latest Yosemite is OS X version 10.10.5. Yosemite is to old and does not have the driver needed to recognize the proprietary internal drive that your Mac would be using.

Comment: I haven't. But I did search a way to replace the OS X Base System (the MacOS image system that is deeply stored, probably in the EFI files) to update it to a newer version. I haven't found a way, yet.